# How to get daily totals for a queryset

Tags: python, django

new Python/Django programmer here. I have been playing with d3.js and I am having some trouble creating a multi-series line chart. I have narrowed down the problem, and I think it's because the data I am sending to d3 has multiple values per day.

My question, should you choose to answer it, is: **How can I calculate the total for each day for each transaction type (credit or debit)?**

Models.py

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    class Transaction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)
    original_description = models.TextField(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    transaction_type = models.TextField(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.TextField(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, null=True)
    account_name = models.TextField(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)
```

dashboard.py

```
import homepage.models as hmod

@view_function
def process_request(request):
    params = {}

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user_session = request.user
        userid = user_session.id
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/homepage/login/')

    trans = hmod.Transaction.objects.all().filter(user_id=userid).values_list('date', 'transaction_type', 'amount', 'category', 'account_name').order_by('date')

    x = 0
    y = 0

    for tran in trans:
        if tran[1] == "credit":
            x += 1
        else:
            y += 1
    print(x)
    print(y)

    trans_json = json.dumps(list(trans), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)

    params['trans_json'] = trans_json

    return templater.render_to_response(request, 'dashboard.html', params)
```

*x and y were just being used to find the total number of transactions of each type while I was struggling to figure it out.

html/script -- only an excerpt. I can include the whole script if that would help

```
//bring json data from dashboard.py
var data = ${trans_json}
...
// Group by transaction_type
    var credit = data.filter(function(d) {
      return d[1] == "credit";;
    });

    var debit = data.filter(function(d) {
      return d[1] == "debit";
    });
 ....
    svg.selectAll('.line')
      .data([debit, credit])
      .enter()
        .append('path')
          .attr('class', 'line')
          .style('stroke', function(d) {
            return colors(Math.random() * 50);
          })
          .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
          .attr('d', function(d) {
            return line(d);
          })
```

With my current setup, the data is returned as a long block of all transaction (grouped by "debit" or "credit) in the format of d="2014-09-12,debit,-9.85,Fast Food,CHECKING..."
But, when I return line(d), I get the ugly error of d="MNaN,160.57661666666664CNaN,160.57661666666664,NaN..."

I have created a line graph following http://bl.ocks.org/markmarkoh/8700606 in the past, but the data I used then only had one entry/day. That's why I'm thinking my error might be that a user tends to have multiple transactions per day making it hard to plot a line.

I am open to any help that you all can provide. If you can help me get the daily total for my queryset and pass it to the script, awesome. Or if there is a better way to accomplish what I wish, I'm happy to scrap and start from another angle.

Thanks!

**Note** If There are small syntax errors (i.e. ${trans_json}) that is probably because I'm using Mako as well in a stack of sorts called django-mako-plus https://github.com/doconix/django-mako-plus
That being said, however, I could have real syntax errors ^^ as well. I tried tagging django-mako-plus, but it seems that's not a tag yet.

Comment: I'm not a django guy but if all you want is counts by date your query should look something like: `hmod.Transaction.objects.all().filter(user_id=userid).values('date').annotate(count = Count('amount')).order_by('date')`

Comment: Thank you. Do you know of a way to get the total for the credit and debit transactions that happened each day?

Comment: Hmmm, can you throw another values in there? `hmod.Transaction.objects.all().filter(user_id=userid).values('transaction_type').values('date').annotate(c‌​ount = Count('amount')).order_by('date')`.  Again I'm not a django user so I'm really just guessing :)

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a Python solution, so I'm removing the D3 tag. Feel free to add it back and clarify the question if that's incorrect.